# Log off from GMail on Android 2.3

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gmail

I have a Samsung Ace, with Android 2.3.6. I logged in with GMail and now I cant log off. I searched a lot of forums etc., but no answer.

I need your help, because it consumes a lot of battery juice and internet traffic.

Comment: It works best when you stay signed in. If you find it's generating too much traffic, you should reduce the frequency at which it synchronizes and perhaps remove the ability for it to sync in the background.

Comment: The same problem is happening with my gingerbread A1+.
As said by ## @izzy, ## option allows deletion, but Google is smart. It warns about all the data deletion and suggests factory reset!

Answer (score 4):

Can you disable gmail sync in Settings > Accounts > [Your gmail account]?

I don't have a Gingerbread device to hand to test this out but it's available in ICS +

Comment: i didint know this site, thanks. butin ICS +, i found an app (1,50€) to exiting safe from gmail and FB, but dont seem honest, to pay for a thing that i should have for free. or is in ICS + anything for free or i could ask something over there?

Comment: What is the application called? You shouldn't require an application to do what you are asking for...

Comment: SignMeOut its the application

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Settings*, select *Accounts & Sync*, select *Gmail Sync*, Select account, and tap *Remove Account* in the bottom...

Comment: if i chose do un sync, when i try to open gmail, appears a message sayng "your email appear soon"... and then i can log in or choose another acount.

Answer (score 0):

If the email ID was given when you purchased it, then it can't be removed in Gingerbread. The only way is to restore it. Don't worry; just back up yur favorite app or share it with a friend. Then, format it. You can clear the GMail account and sent back or back-up the apps. Now, your phone will be smoother and faster.

Comment: I think the answer's still confusing with the way I rephrased it. If you could just make this clearer "You can clear the GMail account and sent back or back-up the apps", it would make more sense. What were you trying to say?